# PHP - Loop Statement syntax incorrect so it never will be executed

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP script and I want to check if a number is between two other numbers like `20< x < 40` but in a very higher range like this:

```
0,400,500,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000,2200,2400,2600,2800,3000,3200,3500,3800,4100,4400,4700,5000
```

I want to check if it is between 0 and 400 then if it is between them echo and if it is not check if it is between 400 and 500 and ... My program is like this :

```
$lt=array(0,400,500,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000,2200,2400,2600,2800,3000,3200,3500,3800,4100,4400,4700,5000);
$lt2=array(399,499,599,799,999,1199,1399,1599,1799,1999,2199,2399,2599,2799,2999,3199,3499,3799,4099,4399,4699,4999,99999);
$value = 5000
$legend = count($lt2);
for ($x = 0; $x == $legend+1; $x++);
{
    if (($value >= $lt[$x]) and ($value < $lt2[$x]))
    {
        $y=$x-1;
        echo "True!";
    }
}
```

My problem is that it never goes into the IF statement. Although my if statement is correct, my number is between two numbers but it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: you realize there's a missing semi-colon `$value = 5000` <= and this looks questionable `$x == $legend+1`

Comment: And I've found too @Fred-ii- `for ($x = 0; $x == $legend+1; $x++);` `<------` What is this?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia TBH, I'm not entirely sure if that should be an assignment or a comparison. I'd have to test their code to make sure.

Comment: So how should i change my program?!

Comment: for ($x = 0; $x == $legend+1; $x++); i meant from 0 untill $x ==$legend so it would be repeated $legend Times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit wrong, but I've fixed it for you:

**Your mistakes:**

Semicolon was missing at `$value = 5000`

`for ($x = 0; $x == $legend+1; $x++);` needs to be changed to:
`for ($x = 0; $x < ($legend - 1); $x++)` Note that you had a semicolon in the for loop, and the condition was wrong.

Moreover, `$y = $x - 1` needs to be rewritten to: `$y = $x;`

```
$lt=array(0,400,500,600,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,1800,2000,2200,2400,2600,2800,3000,3200,3500,3800,4100,4400,4700,5000);
$lt2=array(399,499,599,799,999,1199,1399,1599,1799,1999,2199,2399,2599,2799,2999,3199,3499,3799,4099,4399,4699,4999,99999);
$value = 5000;

$legend = count($lt2);

for ($x = 0; $x < $legend; $x++)
{
    if (($value >= $lt[$x]) && ($value < $lt2[$x]))
    {
        $y = $x;
        echo "True!";
    }
}

echo $lt[$y];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,Work's like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon in this line:

```
$value = 5000
```

Furthermore, the condition `$x == $legend + 1` in your `for` statement cannot be reached. `$legend + 1` is the length of `$lt2` incremented by 1. The length is 0 or higher, so `$x` can never be `$legend + 1`, because it is defined as `$x = 0`.

Probably, you need `$x <= $legend + 1` (Maybe you have to leave out `+ 1`).